# (ReactJS) List of items doesn't get updated on page, even though database gets updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this single page application that uses firebase and reactjs/nodejs that updates/removes/adds html code (body and description). The functions work fine and the data gets updated accordingly in the database. However, the list doesn't refresh once I do any function (only if I press F5 manually). I want the list to dynamically change as I add/edit/delete any of the content. How can I do this?
Here's my code:

HTML.js:

```
const updateByPropertyName = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
  [propertyName]: value,
});

class HTML extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      html: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
db.onceGetHTML().then(snapshot =>
  this.setState(() => ({ html: snapshot.val() }))
);
  }
render() {
const { html } = this.state;
const { description } = this.state;
const { body } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>The Home Page is accessible by every signed in user.</p>

    <input value={description}
      onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('description', event.target.value))}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Description..."
    />
    <input value={body}
      onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('body', event.target.value))}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Body..."
    />
    <button onClick={() => addHTML(description, body)}>Add Content</button>

    {!!html && <HTMLList html={html} />}
  </div>
);
}
}
```

These are all in one file, I just split them to make it easier to read (HTML.js):

```
function addHTML(description, body, callback) {
addAnHTML(description, body);
}
```

And here's the 2nd class in the same file that is responsible for displaying the list of items:

```
class HTMLList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  BODY: '',
  desc: '',
  html: ''
};
  }

render() {
const { html } = this.props;
const { desc } = this.state;
const { BODY } = this.state;

return (
  <div>

    <h2>List of HTML available:</h2>
    {Object.keys(html).map((key, index) =>

      <div>
        {index + 1}.
        {html[key].description}
        <img src="http://www.stilltimecollection.co.uk/images/english/b_delete.gif" onClick={() => deleteHTML(key)} />

        <Popup trigger={<img src="https://www.faktorzehn.org/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/03/f10-org-new_3_6_0-edit.gif" />
        } position="right center">
          <div>
            <input value={desc}
              onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('desc', event.target.value))}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Descripton.."
            />
            <input value={BODY}
              onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('BODY', event.target.value))}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Body..."
            />
            <button onClick={() => updateHTML(key, desc, BODY)}>Update Content</button>
          </div>
        </Popup>
        <br></br>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
}
}
```

The function addAnHTML is in a different file where the database is synchronized:

```
export const addAnHTML = (description, body) => {
var html =
{
  description: description,
  body: body,
  created_at: format.asString(),
  updated_at: ""
}
db.ref('Content').push(html);
alert("Content Added");
}
```

My page looks like this:
https://preview.ibb.co/fTwiaT/Untitled.png

My database looks like this (added in db but not dynamically):
https://image.ibb.co/nNEapo/database.png

**EDIT**: so here's the edit on the functions I use:

```
export const onceGetHTML = () =>
 db.ref('Content').once('value');


 export const addAnHTML = (description, body) => {
  console.log(description);
  console.log(body);
  var html =
    {
      description: description,
      body: body,
      created_at: format.asString(),
      updated_at: ""
    }
  db.ref('Content').push(html);
}
```

and the edited add function in my class looks like this:

```
addContent(description, body) {

this.setState({
  html: [
    ...this.state.html,
    {
      description: this.state.description,
      body: this.state.body
    }
  ]

});
addAnHTML(this.state.description,this.state.body);
}
```

Snapshot.val() contains all the child values of my "Content" parent:
https://preview.ibb.co/jetOc8/edit.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will showcase how to correctly map your data to the DOM for the "add" functionality.

Here is the modified HTML class

```
export class HTML extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      html: [],
      // if you keep your user inputted data in the DOM state, it's good to initialize them first, otherwise your component will suddenly change from an uncontrolled component to a controlled component.
      description: "",
      body: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // EDIT: code here for initializing `html`
    db.onceGetHTML().then(snapshot =>
        // EDIT: it's simpler to just call setState with the new state object you want
        this.setState({ html: snapshot.val()})
    );
  }

  // use class methods to update your DOM state, because inside these methods
  // also don't forget to call your API here
  addContent(description, body) {
    // EDIT: make sure to make your call to the db for adding an entry
    this.setState({
      // please keep in mind that you should NEVER mutate your state, so in here I'm using the spread operator to create a new array instance
      // this is appending a new entry to the old "html"
      html: [
        ...this.state.html,
        {
          description: this.state.description,
          body: this.state.body
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  // use this to update the state for each input field
  updateByPropertyName(property, e) {
    this.setState({
      [property]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { html } = this.state;
    const { description } = this.state;
    const { body } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>The Home Page is accessible by every signed in user.</p>

        <input
          value={description}
          onChange={this.updateByPropertyName.bind(this, "description")}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Description..."
        />
        <input
          value={body}
          onChange={this.updateByPropertyName.bind(this, "body")}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Body..."
        />
        // this onClick event will call "this.setState(...)" which will trigger the re-render (or the "refresh" you are looking for)
        <button onClick={this.addContent.bind(this)}>Add Content</button>

        {!!html && <HTMLList html={html} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will be enough for your successful re-render.

On a side note, it's also useful to index your elements in the list. It's really useful for React to render efficiently. For that, you can modify your HTMList class like so:

```
//...
        <h2>List of HTML available:</h2>
        {Object.keys(html).map((key, index) => (
          // using the index parameter supported in the .map callback it's okay 
          // because it makes your DOM list nodes predictable and easy for React to re-render
          <div key={index}>
            {index + 1}.
            {html[key].description}
            <img
//...
```

For the update and delete you can follow the same pattern, only change the state (in which you hold the `html` object) accordingly.

You can use these readings for the stuff I just explained above

1. [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) vs [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components
2. handling [lists components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in React

Comment: This solution comes up with another problem. If i try to use the old data that already exists there by using the snapshot.val() as shown in my code (instead of html: description(something)...) it will load the data correctly, but when I try to add anything the data is overwritten by the newly added component, then the list functions as I want after that, but I also want to display the old values not only show the added ones. How can I fix that? I believe my problem is with const {html} = this.props; in my HTMLList class. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: if you can please explain to me where the overwrite is happening?

Comment: does snapshot.val() return an Object or an Array? I've updated some stuff for now, can you please paste an exact value of what snapshot.val() is?

Comment: I will update the functions shown in the code at the end of the post, please view them.

Comment: Updated now you can view the picture I put to see what snapshot.val() returns.

Comment: i cannot reproduce your problem. I created a repo with what I have right now. Maybe this way it's easier for you to understand what went wrong? I mocked the data and everytime I add an entry there is no overwrite

Comment: I think it might be something in my HTMLList probably the html = this.props.

Comment: i forgot to paste in the repo, sorry. here it is https://github.com/badraganmircea/html-crud . or even better, maybe post your repo on github so i can take a look at it and fix it

Comment: here is my repo, I added only the files associated. https://github.com/Peril97/reactjs-html

Comment: hi again, I cloned your repo and commented all your service calls (the ones to db) and no data is overwritten. I would guess your bug is somewhere in your service but that I cannot reproduce as I need more info on how to setup the service

Comment: Oh alright, thanks a lot for taking your time, but I think I figured it out. I needed to put the call of the function inside a conditional render and set that boolean to true after adding, seems to work.